# Modification date gets updated when selecting/clicking a file

Tags: document-library, webdav

On our SharePoint site the modification date of files gets updated when it should not, when no changes to a file have been made.

I have found two ways to reproduce this error:

1. A document is opened for read only access. When the document is closed, then the modification date in the library gets updated.
2. When we open the document library in Explorer, every file we click (just single click, highlighting the file) the modification date gets updated too.

I stopped all services on the client machine, to avoid the file being indexed or virus scanned, but it still happens.

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you found that this occurs for all files, or just MS Office files?

Comment: Paul, I don't know how to reply to your question. The probleem seems to occur only with Office files. My guess is that the properties are altered, which makes Sharepoint assume that the document has changed. Which is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any event handlers / timer jobs associated with the libraries?

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that SharePoint will modify Office files by inserting the custom metadata fields that are present on the library into the actual document. This can happen even when a document is opened for viewing. Normally it doesn't change the modification date though.

Comment: I have the same problem. The users click on the file from Document library and select Read only. Then the document library updated the Modified by and date with the

Comment: Sounds like you might have some sort of event handling or workflow like things going on in the background. Normally, just opening a document in either edit or read-only mode should not modify this. The date isn't updated untill you actually save your document back to SharePoint.

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate the symptoms you describe.

You could use something like the [U2U CAML Builder][1] to track down exactly which columns are changing.  You can use it to build CAML queries and it shows you all of the hidden library fields that are used behind the scenes. 

 1. Add the Document
 2. Execute the query with the U2U CAML builder - record the results
 3. Open the Document Library in Explorer View and click on the document
 4. Execute the query with the U2U CAML builder - compare the results with step 2. 


  [1]: http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling in your library the option to "Force checkout to edit document". One alternative could be that you may have Auditing Enabled in the Information Management Policy, under Library settings, which also tracks every "View", however this does not explain entirely why the property get's changed.

Answer (score 0):

If the autosave is enabled, every time you open a document in share-point, without modifying it, the date of the file will update to current date and time. It is one of the disadvantages of the autosave option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a created by and created date by editing your view and selecting those from your column options as well.  it helped us find original versions.